# Why do Unix man pages use double backticks in place of double quotes?

Tags: man, history

I've noticed that man pages and other documents formatted by Unix utilities often use double backticks ``` `` ``` followed by double single quotes `''` to wrap quoted phrases instead of the double quote character `"`. Single quotes are similarly replaced. Why is this?

Here are a couple examples, from the man page for `grep`:

```
 To find all occurrences of the pattern `.Pp' at the beginning of a line:

       $ grep '^\.Pp' myfile

 The apostrophes ensure the entire expression is evaluated by grep instead
 of by the user's shell.  The caret `^' matches the null string at the
 beginning of a line, and the `\' escapes the `.', which would otherwise match
 any character.

 The grep utility is compliant with the IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (``POSIX.1'')
 specification.
```

Comment: I don't have enough for a full answer, but Emacs (in just about all the modes I've seen) has special highlighting for `\`...'`, making it stand out (even within comments).

Comment: Ten years later, `man grep` now has smart quotes: `pattern ‘.Pp’` and `and the ‘\’ escapes the ‘.’`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The semantics and the usual glyphs for these characters have changed
(several times) during the last 50 years.

The six-bit predecessors of ASCII contained various multi-purpose characters,
including one single quote-like
character, which was used for anything that had some similarity with
a quote: opening quote, closing quote,
apostrophe, or (by overprinting) acute or grave accent.

ASCII introduced one more quote-like character, so that now we
had `'`, which was used as apostrophe, closing quote, and
acute accent, and `` ` ``, which was used as opening quote or
grave accent (the concrete glyphs differed in various fonts).

For some bizarre reason, ISO-8859-1 declared `'` to be an
apostrophe or undirected quote, declared `` ` `` to be a
grave accent, added one more accent `´` (acute accent),
*and abolished overprinting* (so that the isolated accent
marks were now completely pointless). Later extensions (MS-Windows
codepages and Unicode) fixed this by introducing new directed quote characters
and combining accents.

What you see here is essentially a relict from ASCII times, when most fonts
had paired (slanted and/or curly) glyphs for `'` and `` ` ``.

Comment: Actually, ISO-8859-1 was irrelevant to *overprinting* and reflects an *effect* rather than a *cause*.  That was lost due to (essentially) no video terminal support for the feature. Hardcopy terminals are unaffected.

Comment: I think using `\`...'` is a "GNU-ism". Recent gcc compilers also use this style of quoting.

Comment: @U.Windl in program output, it is a GNUism, in man pages, it was/is used on UNIX as well.

Answer (score 11):

Output like that is generated by `makeinfo` from [Texinfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo) sources. Texinfo can also [render to other formats like PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texinfo), so it needs to be more expressive than ASCII. Maybe to avoid throwing away semantics, `makeinfo` encodes quotes like that, so you can see what is opening and closing quotes.

Example: If you couldn't see the difference, I can imagine I'd be a bit confusing if you wrote some Texinfo source and relied on the quote difference being visible, because you would have previewed it as PDF. Because you never rendered with `makeinfo`, you'd never discover that it isn't readable, rendered like that.