# Why do shells use a backtick for an opening quote in much of their output?

Tags: bash, zsh

```
$ type -a short_command
short_command is aliased to `some_long_and_obnoxious_command_that_I_never_want_to_type'
```

Why does Bash (and perhaps every other shell) frequently—as above—use a backtick character in place of an opening quotation mark?  And *is there any way to change this?*

Zsh doesn't do it *in that context* and I'm not sure if Zsh itself does this *anywhere* or not, but if Zsh ever does it then I'd also be interested in controlling it there.

Comment: Possibly related: [Why do Unix man pages use double backticks in place of double quotes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73989/why-do-unix-man-pages-use-double-backticks-in-place-of-double-quotes)

Comment: Great, now I can't unsee it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And is there any way to change this?

Starting bash with `LANGUAGE=en@quot` in its environment works for me:

```
bash-5.0$ LANGUAGE=en@quot:en_US:en bash
bash-5.0$ alias foo=bar
bash-5.0$ type foo
foo is aliased to ‘bar’
```

Notice the `‘bar’` (with `U+2018` and `U+2019`) instead of `` `bar' ``

Also look into `LANGUAGE=en@boldquot`. Setting `LANGUAGE` from inside bash does not work, though. Neither does setting `LC_MESSAGES` to `en@quot`.

Have a good time studying the gettext(3) and msgfmt(1) manpages if you want more information.

Comment: This worked on macOS, but failed on Bash version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) on Ubuntu.  Any ideas why that might be?  Does it require Bash 5?

Comment: @iconoclast you probably don't have `en_US` in your locale. What does `env | grep LANG` report? Then use that instead.

Comment: @roaima Inside the shell started as above it shows `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and `LANGUAGE=en@quot:en_US:en`.  Outside that shell it only shows the first one.

Comment: Strange. Works for me (`LANGUAGE=en@quot:en_GB:en`) not only with `bash` version 5.0.3(1)-release but also with version 4.3.30(1)-release.